# How to know if a Firebase has fetched a value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I have three functions `getNewOrder()`,`storeOrderDetails(_ details:[String:String])` and `getUserInfo(_ userID:String)`.

1. Function `getNewOrder()` is called first. It fetches new orders ( .childAdded values) and sends the dictionary to `storeOrderDetails(_ details:[String:String])`.
2. storeOrderDetails(_ details:[String:String])`then segregate all the values and calls`getUserInfo(_ userID:String)` by passing it userID which was present in its details.
3. `getUserInfo(_ userID:String)` then fetches users details and returns user's 
   information.

However, the problem is [ `userInfo = getUserInfo(_ userID:String)` in `storeOrderDetails(_ details:[String:String])` ] userInfo is always empty. Apparently  `func getUserInfo(_ userID:String)`  goes into a completion block after it has returned empty value.

I want these three functions to execute in sequential way.
Any advice is highly appreciated.

Please follow the below Links to review my code.
https://imgur.com/hNjvyDk
https://imgur.com/J0LMXMg

```
 func childAdded(){
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Orders").child(todaysDate)
        ref.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        var details = [String:String]()
       if let orderID = snapshot.key as? String {
               ref.child(orderID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in
                        self.newOrderTextView.text = ""
                        self.customerNameLabel.text = ""
                        self.customerPhoneLabel.text = ""
                        self.orderNumberLabel.text = ""

                        let enumerator = snap.children
                        while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
                        details[rest.key as? String ?? ""] = rest.value as? String ?? ""
                        }
                        self.storeUserDetails(details)
             })
        }
    }
}




func storeUserDetails(_ details:[String:String]){
    if details["CustomerID"]  != nil {
        userInfo = getUserDetails(details["CustomerID"]!)
        print(userInfo)

    }
        if !userInfo.isEmpty{
            let order = OrderDatabase()
        order.customerEmail = userInfo["Email"]!
        order.customerName =  userInfo["Name"]!
        order.orderAcceptStatus = details["OrderStatus"]!
        order.customerOrderNumber = details["orderNumber"]!
        order.orderID = details["orderID"]!
        order.time = details["Time"]!
        order.customerFirebaseID = details["CustomerID"]!
       self.orderDatabase[details["orderNumber"]!] = order
       self.orderTable.reloadData()

    }

}




func getUserDetails(_ userID:String) -> [String:String]{

     var details = [String:String]()
   let userDetailsReference = Database.database().reference().child("Users")
    userDetailsReference.child(userID).observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in



        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
            self.customerNameLabel.text = dictionary.value(forKey: "Name") as? String
            self.customerPhoneLabel.text = dictionary.value(forKey: "Email") as? String

            details["Name"] = dictionary.value(forKey: "Name") as? String
            details["Email"] =  dictionary.value(forKey: "Email") as? String

        }

    })

return details
}
```

Comment: Would you edit your code to show the functions as a whole so we can better assist you.

Comment: you need to put the code here instead of a link to a picture of the code. It's hard to understand your exact problem without seeing the code

Comment: I’m sorry, the code was getting miss aligned over here I tried to post it but for some reason half of the code was properly formatted and rest was in single line. I apologise for inconvenience.

Comment: If you are using XCode you can scoot the text to the left margin, copy and then paste it in your question. Then select the text in the question and use the {} code formatting brackets to format it as code. Voting to close as without code the question has no context and any answer would just be a guess. If you can include code, I would bet we could answer it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see here, I am betting that the issue you are facing has to do with the fact that the methods are asynchronous.  So one thing is not completely finished and some other method gets fired too soon.  There are a few ways to deal with this issue.  One is completion handlers, and the other is adding observers.  Below is an example of doing both for Firebase. Here I'm asking a getLocationPhotos method to get all the photos from Firebase.  Notice the observers and completion handler

```
func getLocationPhotos(coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D){
    dbHandler.getImageFileNames(coordinateIn: coordinate) { (filenames) in

        if filenames.isEmpty {
            log.debug(String.warningGet + "filenames is empty")
            return
        }//if filenames.isEmpty

        self.imageFiles = filenames.filter { $0 != "none" }

        if self.imageFiles.isEmpty {
            log.error(String.errorGet + "imageFiles array is empty")
            return
        }//if imageFiles.isEmpty

        for file in self.imageFiles {
            let reference = self.storageHandler.imageReference.child(file)

            let download = self.imageView.sd_setImage(with: reference)

            if let i = self.imageView.image {
                        self.imageArray.append(i)
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    }//let i

                download?.observe(.progress, handler: { (snapshot) in
                        guard let p = snapshot.progress else {
                            return
                        }//let p
                    self.progressView.progress = Float(p.fractionCompleted)
                    if self.progressView.progress == Float(1) {
                        self.progressView.isHidden = true
                    }
                    })//progress

                download?.observe(.success, handler: { (snapshot) in
                        self.progressView.progress = 1
                        self.progressView.isHidden = true
                        self.collectionView.setNeedsLayout()
                    })//success

                download?.observe(.failure, handler: { (snapshot) in
                        log.error(String.errorGet + "Error occured getting data from snapshot")
                    })//failure
    }//for file
}//dbHandler
```